# Static pictures in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I would like to have 2 pictures in my `UITabeViewController`, one in the top (below the navigationBar) and one in the bottom (above the tabBar). What I want to do, is when you scroll the `tableView`, theses images will stay static and won't move.

How is it possible to do that ?

Thank's!

Comment: How about just making the table view smaller and putting UIImageViews above and below?

Comment: @borrrden, Please write this as an answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just making the table view smaller and putting UIImageViews above and below?

Comment: Good solution ! But what about UITableViewController ? I can't make it smaller. But if there is no solution for this one, I will change it to a simple UIViewController.

Comment: I've never used UITableViewController, even when I make a table, because I feel strangled by its lack of customization.  However, you can add a UITableViewController as a child view controller of another view controller, and have its view be small.  I think that just writing your own view controller is less hassle though.  Just implement the two tableview protocols, add a tableview and set the delegate to the controller and boom, in 2 minutes you have your own UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You has some thing wrong. You need it's only a UIViewController, which has a tableview and two imageView. 
UITableView must scroll all it's content view. UITableView has two part: a large content view, a small clipping view. when you scroll table view, it has chage the content view's visible range。